# Balls, Bags, Partitions, and Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

We have $n$ **distinct** colored balls and $m$ **similar** bags( with the condition $n \geq m$ ). In how many ways can we place these $n$ balls into given $m$ bags?

**My Attempt**: For the moment, if we assume all the balls are of same color - we are counting partitions of $n$ into at most $m$ parts( since each bag looks same - it is not a composition of $n$, just a partition ).

But, given that each ball is unique, for every partition of $n$ ----> $\lambda : \{\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \cdots \lambda_m\}$, we've $\binom{n}{\lambda_1} * \binom{n-\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}*\binom{n-\lambda_1-\lambda_2}{\lambda_3}* \cdots * \binom{\lambda_{m-1}+\lambda_{m}}{\lambda_{m-1}}*\binom{\lambda_m}{\lambda_m}$ ways of arranging the balls into $m$ given baskets. We need to find this out for every partition of $n$ into $m$ parts.

Am i doing it right?

I'm wondering whether there is any closed form formula for this( i know that enumerating the number of partitions of $n$ is also complex. But, i don't know, the stated problem seemed simple at the first look. But, it isn't? Am i right? ).

**P.S.** I searched for this question thinking that somebody might have asked it earlier. But, couldn't find it. Please point me there if you find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is counting the maps from an $n$-set (the balls) to an $m$-set (the bags), up to permutations of the $m$-set (as the bags are similar). This is just one of the problems of the [twelvefold way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way), and looking at the [appropriate section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelvefold_way#Functions_from_N_to_X.2C_up_to_a_permutation_of_X) you find that the result can only be expressed as a sum of Stirling numbers of the second kind, namely $\sum_{k=0}^m\genfrac\{\}0{}nk$. The $k$ in fact represents the number of nonempty bags here.

Comment: Thanks, shouldn't k start from 1.

Comment: @Novice: No $k$ should start from $0$ so that the formula will remain true for the case $n=0$. In fact $\genfrac\{\}0{}n0=\delta_{n,0}=0^n$.